# Chain 2 transactions in bitcoin

Tags: transactions, balance

Is it possible to have, in the same block, a transaction from A to B and then another transaction from B to C if the initial balance of B is 0 ?

Or the node is going reject the second transaction because the first one need to be validated to update the balance of B